# How to get rid of the white loading bar on BlackBerry Browser after page loads

Tags: html, css, web-applications, blackberry, web

I have a project where I've had to build a web app targeted at Blackberry devices (Specifically the 8520)

The problem is that it seems like the 8520 has some kind of loading bar that appears at the bottom of the page, but doesn't go away after everything has loaded.

Is this a CSS thing or not? I can't figure it out.

For the CSS, I have the following related to the layout:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

body {
    font-family:'BBAlpha sans', Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#container {
    width:311px;
    height:218px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the height of the #container?

Comment: yea, the height I set is exactly that of the screen minus the menu bar at the top

Comment: Hmm...can you set it up so that your app will listen for the loading to be complete, then report the height of itself. I'm thinking it could possibly be cause of using 100% as the dimension, so when it's done what you see it what 100% was while the loading bar was shown.

Comment: Hmmm... looks like 100% works out to the same height as set in #container :(

Comment: @jprofitt you were right, it was indeed the 100% height that was causing the problem. It also seems that the browser on the 8520 has a broken document loaded event.

If you create an answer to this question mentioning the height, I can mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking it could possibly be caused by using 100% as the dimension, so when it's done what you see what 100% was while the loading bar was shown. For example, when the loading bar is showing, only 200 pixels might be available as the height, and then once it's gone the screen will have 220. The app might not be refreshing its height after the loading bar is gone.